# Bonding characteristic polynomial by Rouché's theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory

Let $\chi = X^n + a_{n-1}X^{n-1} + \cdots + a_0$ a characteristic polynomial in $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$. Assumle the coefficients are inetegers and that I have a uniform bound on the, say $|a_i| \leq C$ for all $i$. Is Rouché theorem yielding a bound for roots of this polynomial from bounds on the coefficients?

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(z) = z^n+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+\cdots +a_o$ and $g(z) = z^n$.

Suppose $|z| > C+1$.

Then $|f(z)-g(z)| \le C(1+|z|+\cdots + |z|^{n-1})= C {|z|^n-1 \over |z|-1} < |z|^n -1 < |g(z)| $.

Hence $f,g$ have the same number of zeros in $|z| \le C+1$.